# How do I convert MM:SS:splits to MM:SSSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have an audio tag that looks like this: "`00:14:164`", i.e. "`MM:SS:splits`".

I'd like to have the format be numeric and only in the seconds unit.

So for example:

"`00:14:164`" would be `14.164`

and

"`01:59:582`" would be `119.582`

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Are you looking to just display the value in seconds in the view or actually store it in seconds in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def tag_to_f(tag)
  a = tag.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  "#{a[0] * 60 + a[1]}.#{a[2]}".to_f
end

tag_to_f "01:59:582"
```

Or monkey patch `String`:

```
class String
  def to_f_with_audio_tag
    if a = match(/^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/).to_a[1..3].map(&:to_i) rescue nil
      "#{a[0] * 60 + a[1]}.#{a[2]}".to_f_without_audio_tag
    else
      to_f_without_audio_tag
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :to_f, :audio_tag
end

"01:59:582".to_f
```